Simplifying a vector equation.
Given $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are non coplanar vectors
Prove the following
$$(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{c}\times\vec{a}+(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=[\vec{b} \vec{c} \vec{a}]\vec{a}$$
What I did was assume $\vec{a}$ As the linear combination of  of the 3 cross products of the given vectors in the equation
I expressed the vector $\vec{a}$  as the linear combination of the 3 cross products so I first need to show that those vectors are not coplanar
As $(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})\cdot((\vec{c}\times\vec{a})\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}))$
Simplifies to $[\vec{b} \vec{c} \vec{a}]^2$ which is clearly non zero as the initial vectors are not coplanar
From there I took dot product of Vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b},\vec{c}$  one by one to determine the required coefficient
I got the required equation from there
What I wanted to ask is that is it possible to simply manipulate the LHS to somehow reach the RHS I am asking because I've solved a lot of similar problems till now my book also gave some illustrations regarding such problems but in almost all of them they used the same approach and when I tried to simplify that equation I see no way as the coefficients are dot products and the vectors associated with those coefficients are cross products and I don't know any way to break down those cross products or to combine those different vector products the only way I see is to write the vector in terms of their $x,y,z$ components and their dot and cross products and that calculation is clearly just horrible , so I wonder is it even possible to simply on vector equation if yes please show it with the above equation.

What is $[\vec b\ \vec c\ \vec a]$?

@ultralegend5385 Triple product

$
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin\lfloor}
$I assume $[bca] = b\cdot(c\times a)$ is the triple product. This can be done with geometric algebra.
Let $I$ be the right-handed unit pseudoscalar. Then
$$
  I[bca]a = (b\wedge c\wedge a)a = (b\wedge c\wedge a)\rcontr a = (b\wedge c)(a\cdot a) - (b\wedge a)(c\cdot a) + (c\wedge a)(b\cdot a).
$$
Now multiply each side by $I^{-1}$ and use the fact that $a\times b = I^{-1}(a\wedge b)$ to finally get
$$
  [bca]a = (b\times c)(a\cdot a) - (b\times a)(c\cdot a) + (c\times a)(b\cdot a)
$$
as desired.

I've realized that using　standard vector algebra we can do the following (though I think it is much uglier than the above):
$$\begin{aligned}
  &(a\cdot a)b\times c + (a\cdot b)c\times a + (a\cdot c)a\times b \\&= [(a\cdot a)b - (a\cdot b)a]\times c + (a\cdot c)a\times b \\&= [a\times(b\times a)]\times c + (a\cdot c)a\times b \\&= -[c\cdot(b\times a)]a + (c\cdot a)b\times a + (a\cdot c)a\times b \\&= [cab]a \\&= [bca]a.
\end{aligned}$$

Well ,I  don't know what is 'right-handed unit pseudoscalar' nor I know what does $\wedge$ mean, nor there is something like that in my book so I think I will learn these things later.

@Anonymous123 Well, you asked if it was possible, and my answer is essentially just "it is". I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this with just standard vector algebra, unfortunately, otherwise I would have done that... is what I would have said, but I think a found a way...

@Anonymous123 See my edit.
